# How to create two cascade NSPopUp button with Core-Data binding

Tags: core-data, binding, cascade, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

need some help.

I'm already add two popup button, and two NSArrayController.

- first is parent (named as Country).
- second is child (named as City), with content set bind (CountryController.selected.cities)
- In the first PopUpButton (Select Country) bind Content (CountryController.ArrangedObjects), Content Values (CountryController.ArrangedObjects.title).
- In the second PopUpButton (Select City) bind Content (CityController.ArrangedObjects), Content Values (CityController.ArrangedObjects.title).

but have not cascade (Country->Cities) :(
the question may be noob, but please help if you know :(