# Populating Master-Detail NSPopUp from Core Data

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

Here is my CoreData model.  The relationship is unordered.

[image: cd model]

I would like to have this model populate a pair of NSPopUp buttons like this:

[image: cd model]

When the team popup is selected, the player popup should populate with the applicable players of the selected team which will then be selected by the user.

Here is what I have tried:

I've created two NSArrayControllers, **TeamList** and **PlayerList**, both set to entity mode, with the CD-moc.  For my bindings, I do the following:

Bind the team popup *content* to **TeamList** with *controller Key* arrangedObjects

Bind the team popup *content values* to **TeamList** with *controller Key* arrangedObjects and *Model Key Path* teamName

Bind the player popup *content* to **PlayerList** with *controller Key* arrangedObjects 

Bind the player popup *content values* to **PlayerList** with *controller Key* arrangedObjects and *Model Key Path* playerName

This seems to be working, without any regard for the CD relationship (it shows all players in the player popup).

To inflict the relationship, I attempt the following:

Bind the **PlayerList** array controller *content set* to **TeamList** with *controller key* selection and *model key path* playerList.

This initially pulls in the subset of the players for the "selected" team, but doesn't repopulate when the user alters the Team popup.

BTW, I believe this (unanswered) question was asked here:
[How to create two cascade NSPopUp button with Core-Data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170831)

**Any hints on how I can make this work?**

What would be a real bonus is to have only one popup with embedded submenus (Team > Player).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see you binding the team popup’s selection with the TeamList array controller selection, so it makes sense the PlayerList would stick with the initial selection in the master.